# Linux: mount and umount as a user without fstab

Tags: linux, mount

I am writing this software that creates virtual block device nodes almost like loop does. I need to allow non-superusers to mount and umount filesystems from these devices. I don't know the names of the block device nodes beforehand so i can't use fstab entries to add "user" or "owner" flags there.

Currently i solve this by providing a small suid helper tool that verifies that this is indeed "my" block device the user is trying to mount and then just call /sbin/mount or /sbin/umount to do the job. This is definitely better than setting a suid bit for the whole program but not really perfect. Is there a better way?

Inso.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the [pmount](https://launchpad.net/pmount) program can help you. Another option is setting sudo rules. The sudo program does allow you to define some pretty specific rules once you grok its config syntax.

Comment: I'm taking a look at pmount. Without me installing it first, can you say if it will (or should) work with archivemount? Thanks

Comment: @MountainX Do you have, or do you use, an fstab file? If so, you might just try the *user* option there first.

Comment: Yes, I can use fstab. But I don't know the syntax when using archivemount with fstab and I couldn't find examples anywhere.

Comment: I have googled to the best of my ability to find achievemount fstab examples. I have not found relevant/helpful results yet.